# Haskell fixed point signature

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

What is the signature of the following Haskell function:

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

a) ((a->b)->a->b)->a->b

b) The signature can not be synthesized

c) (a->a)->a

Thanks!

Comment: You can try putting it in REPL and see it for yourself.

Comment: More specifically define `fix` in GHCi with `let fix f = f (fix f)` and then ask for its type with `:t fix`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't want to do your homework either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the type of this function (a -> a) -> a?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918990/why-is-the-type-of-this-function-a-a-a)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question looks like an course homework / test question. I'll help you to find the solution yourself:

First you probably have GHC installed, so you can run `ghci` a haskell repl.

There is [a section in GHC users' guide about GHCi](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html). Yet it's quite long.

If you start up the GHCi you'll get a prompt, where you can type Haskell expressions:

```
Prelude> 1 + 1
2
Prelude> map (\x -> x + x) [1, 2, 3]
[2,4,6]
```

You can also bind expression to names, and define functions:

```
Prelude> let fix f = f (fix f)
```

And one of the most powerful features is to ask for the type of the expression:

```
Prelude> :t map (\x -> x + x)
map (\x -> x + x) :: Num b => [b] -> [b]
Prelude> :t fix
... output omitted
```

That's how you find a solution to your problem. After you know that, you could ask why the type of `fix` is what it is.

Answer (score 2):

A completely different approach: finding the solution through reasoning.

The right hand side is

```
f (fix f)
```

so `f` has the type `a -> b` for some types `a` and `b`, since `f` is a function.

In other words, the value of `f (fix f)` has type `b`, and `fix f` has the type `a`.

Since, by definition,

```
fix f = f (fix f)
```

`fix f` must have the same type as `f (fix f)`, i.e. `b`.

We have already said that `a` is the type of `fix f`, so `a` and `b` must be the same type.

Let's call it `t` to keep things separate.

So `f : t -> t`, since `a` and `b` were the same type `t`.
We know that `fix f` has the type `b`, which we renamed `t`.

Putting `f : t -> t` and `fix f : t` together we get

```
fix : (t -> t) -> t
```

which is alternative c).

---

Aside: if we substitute `a -> b` for `t` we get

```
((a -> b) -> (a -> b)) -> (a -> b)
```

or, since the arrow associates to the right:

```
((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> a -> b
```

which is exactly the answer in a).
So a) is almost correct, but not general enough.

Comment: Why you don't stop at `fix :: (t -> t) -> t`. That's the correct and principal HM type, which is equal (modulo renaming) to *c)*. I'd say, both *a)* and *c)* are correct, if question is multiple choice. Or then either one is ok (any correct type).

Comment: @phadej I did stop there, but I edited to hopefully make it a bit clearer that I did. The aside at the end is there to explain that alternative a) isn't general enough.